# "have to" a phrasal verb

Tags: grammar, phrasal-verbs, modal-verbs

Why is "have to" not listed as a phrasal verb in the dictionary? "have" means to be in possession of something while "have to" means "obliged to". So "have to" seem to be non-compositional in terms of meaning with respect to the meanings of "have" and "to". Can "obligation" be expressed using the word "have" without it being followed by "to"?

Comment: Being non-compositional does not make something a phrasal verb. In fact, _have to_ is an [idiomatic modal auxiliary](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/Modality.pdf), paraphrasing _must_. It is certainly not a [phrasal verb](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/words/370/Englishphrasalverbs.pdf), which has completely different syntax.

Comment: It's not a phrasal verb but a phrasal *modal*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Various grammatical sects profess various dogmata about phrasal verbs, but *have to* doesn't really fit any of them. That *to* isn't an ordinary preposition or adverb married to *HAVE*—it's a some-other-sort-of-particle married to the infinitive which follows.

One simple test:

> <sup>ok</sup> I can’t put up with him. → It’s him I can’t put up with. → He’s who I can’t put up with.
>
> <sup>ok</sup> She’s into metal. → It’s metal’s she’s into.  → Metal’s what she’s into.
>
> <sup>∗</sup> We have to hurry.  → It’s hurry we have to. → Hurry’s what we have to.

The same thing is true of the other periphrastic modals: *BE able to*, *BE about to*, *BE going to*, and so forth. They don’t behave like the other things that are called phrasal verbs so you need to call them something else.

Comment: Would you agree that semantic composition does not provide "have to" with its meaning?

Comment: @Baz Not entirely. Historically, *HAVE to VERB X* is a variant of *HAVE X to VERB*.

Comment: Putting aside the vexed question of the *exact* definition of "phrasal verb", I just eyeballed [this fairly long list](http://www.englishclub.com/vocabulary/phrasal-verbs-list.htm) of terms which *are* considered to fall into the category. I don't see any that include the *"infinitive" **to***. Phrasal verb it ain't.

Comment: "[Complementizer](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/complementtypes.pdf)" is the other-sort-of-particle name, @StoneyB. _For-to,_ `POSS`-_ing,_ `ACC`-_ing, that, Wh_-`Q` are the principal ones in English.

Comment: @JohnLawler Yeah, I've learned to like that one better than *infinitive marker*, though I'm wondering if maybe *nominalizer* might not be even better, since it works with infinitives which aren't complements, too.

Comment: But they're always shortened from tensed complement, relative. or adverb clauses, which are fundamentally the same thing and use the same set of markers (wh- and that) as complement clauses.

Comment: @JohnLawler What about appositives? "My object all sublime, I shall achieve in time, to make the punishment fit the crime, the punishment fit the crime."

Comment: Deleted "is". My object is to make ... That's a subject complement.

Comment: @JohnLawler Eh? "In time I shall achieve my sublime object: to make the punishment fit the crime". Deleted *which is*, if you insist, though my own feeling is that that's a bit Procrustean.

Comment: That's the way I'd read it; _I shall achieve in time_ is a non-restrictive relative without _which_. _To make the punishment fit the crime is my object all sublime. Reverse or extrapose the infinitive subject. But you might be right, too. Lots has been left out, or put in, or smeared over, in pursuit of meter and rhyme. As Sullivan put it in a different context, "This particularly rapid unintellible patter isn't generally heard, and if it is it doesn't matter".

Comment: 'Grammatical sects'. Marvellous.